# Powershell remote execution

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

PS newbie here...

I am attempting to run the following script:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName hyper-V hostname
$VMList = Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'}
    foreach ($VM in $VMList)
    {
     Write-Host $VM.VMName
    }
Exit-PSSession
```

When I execute the commands individually I get the anticipated data returned.  For example I run the Enter-PSSession and it commects to the remote computer.  I run the foreach loop and it returns the list of vms running on the host.  Then I run the Exit-PSSession and it closes the connection.

However when I try to run the code all together I don't get the list of runnings vms.

Ideas...Suggestions?

Comment: Given that you're referring to your code "*as-is*", you need to declare some form of statement termination. You can do so by placing each command in a new line, or separating by a semicolon. Also, you don't have to use `Enter-PSSession` (*as it won't allow the execution of what follows*) when you can just *invoke* the command but, `Get-Vm` offers remote capability so you can just specify the remote computer: `Get-Vm -ComputerName Vm`. Or, using: `Invoke-Command { Get-VM | Where State -eq 'Running' } -ComputerName Vm`.

Comment: [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.2) Starts an _interactive session_ with a remote computer. When you run it as a script, what follows won't be run on the remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

[`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.2) is meant for interactive shells, if you want to run a script unattended that will connect to a remote host, the cmdlet you should be using is [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$VMList = Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'hyper-V hostname' -ScriptBlock {
    Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty VMName
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and it did not return any data...I verified there are 15 guests running on that host

Comment: @Brently The code is doing the same as your script but non-interactive where as your code is interactive. Try removing `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty VMName` and see if that produces any output. Also make sure you have the right ComputerName here `-ComputerName 'hyper-V hostname'`